# Spring scheduler - getting time of next event

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I've got a SpringBoot Scheduler that looks like this:

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * * ")   // Every 10 seconds
    public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
    }
```

I'd like to get the time of the next event, so I can print it out at the end of each event.  I've read about using `CronExpression`, which has a next() method, but not sure how I get the CronExpression.  OR do I create a CronExpression and somehow pass it in instead of using the `@Scheduled` annotation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I can get accurate interval time but I can get roughly correct next running time from following code.

```
@Value("${cron.schedule}") String schedule;

@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.schedule}")   // Every 10 seconds
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
    var expression = CronExpression.parse(schedule);
    var result = expression.next(LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your cron string (that you use in the `@Scheduled` annotation) as a final field of your class, and then create `CronExpression` from it to find out the next trigger date.

Also, instead of using `@Scheduled` annotation, you can take a look at Spring's `TaskScheduler` (from the package `org.springframework.scheduling`). It has the method `TaskScheduler#schedule` with two arguments: a `Runnable` that will run in background and a `CronTrigger` to set the cron expression and and the timezone of executing background tasks.

UPD. One other way to reuse your cron is set it in your `application.properties` and use within `@Value` and `@Scheduled` annotations, e.g. `@Scheduled(cron = ${property.from.file})`. In this case you can also change the cron expression before running your application if needed.